# Unable to have concurrent log-ins with Google auth

Tags: java, angular, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a web app where users have to authenticate using Google sign-in.  I do this because I need to grab their email address.  When they fill out the fields on the page, all that data is stored in a google sheet alongside their email address (for auditing purposes incase something is askew with the data).  Unfortunately what's happening is that if user A signs in, and does some work and at the same time user B logs in, when user A submits data, they will be submitting user B's email address (as does user B).  In short, the latest person to log in, that email address is used.  There is no database and I'm not storing any cookies.  When they refresh the page, they have to re-authenticate.  I am using Angular 7 and Java.  Here is the code that I used:

```
ngOnInit() {
  gapi.load('auth2', () => {
    this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'CLIENT_ID_HERE',
      // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    });
  });
}

signInWithGoogle(): void {
  this.auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then((authResult) => {
    this.authCode = authResult['code'];
    this.fetchData();
  });
}
```

authCode is bound to the child component so it can be passed as query param to the java code for google auth.

```
this.seriesService.submitSeriesData(matchList, this.authToken).subscribe(res => {.....);
```

The google auth java code is so:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_DIR = "/client_secret.json";

private static GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = null;

public static String getEmailAddress() throws IOException {
        GoogleIdToken idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();
        GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
        String email = payload.getEmail();
        return email;
}

public static Sheets getSheetsService1(String token, String redirectUri) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        // Exchange auth code for access token
    InputStream in = GoogleAuthUtil.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_DIR);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        tokenResponse =
                  new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                      new NetHttpTransport(),
                      JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                      clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
                      clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
                      token,
                      redirectUri)
                  .execute();

        String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);

        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
                .setApplicationName("MY APP HERE")
                .build();

        return service;
}
```

And the endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="series/data", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public boolean submitSeriesMatchData(@RequestBody(required=true) SubmitStatsDto request) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, Exception {
  if (service == null) {
    service = GoogleAuthUtil.getSheetsService1(request.getToken(), this.redirectUri);
  }
  ......
}
```

1) User clicks on the google sign in button
2) They select email and auth with google
3) I receive an auth code back and store it in ng.
4) Every REST call is passed said token to auth with google, and every endpoint calls getSheetsService1 which authenticates w/ token. (multiple endpoints, I only showed one above)
5) I get email from that tokenResponse.

Any ideas?  This site will not have a database/users/local logins.  Thank you.

Comment: If you use neither a database nor cookies, you have no way of tracking who is logged in.

Comment: When I store the auth token in the authToken, doesn't the browser store the js vars per user?  How is it possible that user B's auth token be used for user A?

Comment: Because you're storing it statically in your server code for all requests.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand though.  The authToken is being passed into every API call, how could the server code be storing the auth code?  Wouldn't tokenResponse be created on every API call?

Comment: You should not store things in non-constant `static` fields.

Comment: Thank you for your response!